# place order error in magento

Tags: magento, checkout

After upgrading my magento installation to the latest (1.6.1.0), I noticed a popup error message at the final checkout stage (when pressing the "Place Order" button). The message says: "There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later."

Everytime I try to place an order, I get this error message.. How can I fix it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer your question, as you haven't provided the information about the checkout. 
Are you using a one-step checkout? Have you installed a module?

Probably, changes in your Magento configuration have been done, which lead to this error.